# Rendering Ember view with helpers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ember.js, jsfiddle

I have read the [ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) to achieve the same in my Ember Application, but i can't.

I am trying to configure my view with a Controller which makes a multiplication between two values

Here the code:

```
App.TotalView = Ember.View.extend({
 attributeBindings: ['value', 'placeholder'],
 placeholder: null,
 value: '',
 total: (function() {
    return this.get('newThread.selectContentTariffa') * this.get('newThread.primary');
    }).property('newThread.selectContentTariffa', 'newThread.primary')
});
```

Here in the view:

```
<td>{{view "total" valueBinding=newThread.value}}</td>
```

I can not get the result of this multiplication in this view,is this code correct? what's wrong?

You can see here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qakado/edit

Comment: I have seen your bin. I am get confused. Instead of telling what is wrong May i know what do you want to achieve, so that i can rewrite it. I guess you complicating for the simple task. Please update your usecase

Comment: I have minified the jsbin so it s possible to see clearer the issue

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qakado/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By only focusing on the issue you are facing and not the design and based on the code you have provided, there are the following issues and corresponding possible solutions applied to the examples at the end,

1. there are calls to `newThread` but it is not defined anywhere - create a `newThread` in controller
2. the view helper uses `total` you may either create a template and associate it with `App.TotalView` or use the block form of view helper - 1st example uses a template, 2nd uses block form

**js**

```
App.ThreadsController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({

   selectContentTariffa: [
     {label: "180", value: "180"},
     {label: "200", value: "200"},
     {label: "300", value: "300"}
   ],

  newThread:{
    value:null,
    selectContentTariffa:null,
    primary:null
  }


});


App.TotalView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"total",
 attributeBindings: ['value', 'placeholder'],
 placeholder: null,
 value: '',
 total: (function() {
    var res= parseInt(this.get('controller.newThread.selectContentTariffa')) * parseInt(this.get('controller.newThread.primary'));
   return isNaN(res)?"":res;
    }).property('controller.newThread.selectContentTariffa', 'controller.newThread.primary')
});
```

**hbs - example1**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="threads">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr><th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th><th>Title 3</th></tr>

        <tr>
        <td>{{view Ember.Select prompt="Tariffa" valueBinding=newThread.selectContentTariffa content=selectContentTariffa optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label"}}</td>
        <td>{{view Em.TextField type="number" valueBinding=newThread.primary class="form-control"}}</td>
        <td>{{view "total"}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="total">
  this is total:{{view.total}}
  </script>
```

**hbs-example2**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="threads">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr><th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th><th>Title 3</th></tr>

        <tr>
        <td>{{view Ember.Select prompt="Tariffa" valueBinding=newThread.selectContentTariffa content=selectContentTariffa optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label"}}</td>
        <td>{{view Em.TextField type="number" valueBinding=newThread.primary class="form-control"}}</td>
        <td>{{#view "App.TotalView"}}t:{{view.total}}{{/view}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

example1 - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/falafezijo/edit?html,js

example2 - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cuxafigiqe/1/edit?html,js